# Has the given statement regarding Set Theory been correctly stated in the form of a logical statement using logical symbols?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's assume that we have a statement, stated in words as follows:

> If $A \subseteq B \implies$ for any given value of $x$ such that $x \in A$, it will imply that $x \in B$

Now, let's assume that we have to write this as a single logical statement, how would we do this? The first thing that came to my mind was :
$$A \subseteq B \implies x \in A \implies x \in B$$
But, this feels more like : "If $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $x$ will belong to $A$ and $B$". It feels like we're stating this for an already given value of $x$ rather than for any value of $x$ such that it belongs to $A$.

Another method I thought of was by using parenthesis, but I don't know if it's right. This is what I thought of :
$$A \subseteq B \implies (x \in A \implies x \in B)$$
The one mentioned below seems to be the best to me. I use the $\forall$ symbol in it. In the statement in words, it's stated that "for *any* given value of $x$ such that...", which according to me can be replaced by "for *all* values of $x$ such that..." to obtain this :
$$A \subseteq B \implies \forall x \in A \implies x \in B$$

I want to know which one of these are right and which one (not necessarily out of these) is the most appropriate one to use.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be $A\subseteq B \Leftrightarrow (x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B \space \forall x\in A)$

Comment: That looks pretty promising, thanks for the $\iff$ symbol too. On a different note, I really like what you say about logic in your profile. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case we have a *definition* for subset in terms of set theory. Think of *definitions* as "if and only if" i.e. $\iff$. In terms of symbols, we have:
$$
A \subseteq B \iff \big( x \in A \implies x \in B\big).
$$
Hope this clears it up.

Comment: This looks good, thanks! Also, please take a look at the comment by @student where he uses $\forall x \in A$ at the end. Does that make the statement clearer?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu I saw the comment. The "$\forall x\in A$" is redundant in my opinion, because you are already specifying $x \in A$ in the hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!